# Difference between generate and base?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that when the dimension of a real vector space is equal to the number of given linearly independent vectors, then they generate the vector space and form a basis.
I found this article on wikipedia about linear independence:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence

Can somebody explain to me what it means that 3 vectors generate a vector space (e.g $\Bbb R^3$) and how is it different from being a basis?

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @Carsten when we have for example 3 vectors inside $\Bbb R^3$ then we know that these vectors generate it. Is that wrong?

Comment: That is a much clearer statement, and it is wrong if these vectors are not linearly independent. Take for example $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$,$\,\!$ $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say a set $\left\{ v_i \right\}_{i \in I}= M \subset V$ of vectors generates a $K$-vector space $V$ means, that for every $x \in V$ you can write $x =\sum_{i \in I} a_i v_i$ with the $a_i \in K$ and only finitely many of them non-zero.

In common language: every element of $V$ is a finite linear combination of $M$.

However, this doesn't say anything about uniqueness. The definition of a basis now implies that every element of $V$ can be written in a *unique way* as a linear combination of $M$. (which is nothing else but linear independence)

In the case of finite dimensional vector spaces, there are a lot of nice properties. For example any generating set with cardinality $\dim V$ is already a basis. Same is true for a minimal generating set, that is a set $M$ which after removing a vector $v$ from it won't generate $V$ anymore. You should not confuse those properties with the definition of a basis though. As long as working with finite dimensional vector spaces (i.e. groups over fields) this works out well, but soon you will discover the notion of a module where things aren't as nice.

For example you can consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, which has a basis $\left\{ 1 \right\}$. But also $\left\{ 2,3 \right\}$ with the definition above would be a minimal generating set, as after removing one of the elements you could only generate integers divisible by $2$ or $3$. The set $\left\{ 2,3 \right\}$ is not a basis though, as you can represent $0$ in many different ways, for example $0 = 0 \cdot 2 + 0 \cdot 3$ or $0 = -3 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot 2$. Hence uniqueness doesn't work out here.

Now to finish, let me give you an example of a generating set of a *vector space* which is not a basis. We take the one dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}$ with again the set $\left\{ 2,3\right\}$. Now obviously this is a generating set, as we can write $a = \frac{a}{2} \cdot 2$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. But we can also write $a = \frac{a}{3} \cdot 3$ which doesn't work out once again with the uniquess we had required for the linear combination when defining a basis.

Now this example looks quite similar to the one just given above, but here the difference is, that what I had stated as a fact about bases of a vector space is not vulnerated: $\left\{ 2,3\right\}$ is not a minimal generating set of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}$, as for example $\left\{ 2\right\} \subset \left\{ 2,3\right\}$ still works.

Answer (score 3):

One can define the vector space generated by any set of vectors. However, if they are linearly dependent, you can remove some of the vectors from the set and get the *same* vector space when letting the remaining vectors in the set generate a space.

In other words, if you let a linearly dependent set of vectors generate a vector space then some of the vectors are superfluous; they can be removed without any harm. It is precisely in the situation where the set of vectors is linearly *independent* that we call it a basis.